# Xamarin.Forms Listview with rotated labels

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

Just having a play with `Xamarin.Forms` and I wanted to create a `ListView` with rotated labels. I managed to get the labels to rotate but they overlap each other. I am guessing the ListView Items Height is not adjust to the rotation.

This is my code

```
  <ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ListView" BackgroundColor="Black">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ContentView Rotation="-90" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="100">
            <Label BackgroundColor="#41b5e8" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
          </ContentView>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

I tried binding to the `Label` `Width` which seems to stop the overlap but it doesn't seem to take the margin of the label into account.

```
  <ContentView Rotation="-90" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference Label}, Path=Width}" >
     <Label x:Name="Label" BackgroundColor="#41b5e8" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="12"/>
  </ContentView>
```

UPDATE 1:
Thanks to Adam Pedley, I now have the rotation working right. Now I have an issue with the text position of the label. I would like it central in both horizontal and vertical but doing the following my text appears off.

```
<Grid x:Name="Layout" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ListView" BackgroundColor="Green" SeparatorVisibility="None" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ContentView Rotation="-90" BackgroundColor="#41b5e8" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference Label}, Path=Width}">
            <Label x:Name="Label" BackgroundColor="Red" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
          </ContentView>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>

  <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <ContentView x:Name="Button1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BindingContext="{Binding WeekDay}"/>
      <Button Text="DAY 2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
      <Button Text="DAY 3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

    </Grid>

  </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Which displays like this

[image]

If I then change the column definition to `<ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>` in `Layout Grid` i get this.
[image]

Comment: you should try replacing margin with padding.

Answer (score 1):

Margin is not included in the calculation, only padding would be. Hence you would want to add padding to your ContentView.

```
<ContentView Rotation="-90" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference Label}, Path=Width}" Padding="12" >
     <Label x:Name="Label" BackgroundColor="#41b5e8" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like I am almost there. Any idea how to address the text position issue? See my update.

Comment: I'm not sure how its looking on your end, but I would try adding HorizontalOptions, HorizontalTextAlignment, VerticalOptions and VerticalTextAlignment to the Label. A good trick is to also set the background color of the label and ContentView some different colors. It then shows you what component is where and which element is causing the alignment issue. Once we know what i causing the issue, we can focus on setting those properties.

Comment: Just updated my post with screenshots so that you can see what the issue is.

Comment: @Gaz83 - just to clarify, how do you want the images to look as the first screenshot you are showing looks right to me, so it must mean I am misunderstanding the exact layout you need.

Comment: the first screenshot looks correct, the items in the `Listview` are centre of the `Listview`. When the `Listview` has resized, like in the second screenshot, the items are now not centre to the `listview`.